# Woocommerce Dump New Order Details in MySQL Table

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I looking to get basic details such as `Order ID`, `Name` and `Phone` of customer when new order is placed on woocommerce and then save it into a seperate MySQL Table.

Here is code which I am trying but it is just stroing order id but not the name and phone.

```
function add_db($order_id)
{
    // order object (optional but handy)
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("wordpress") or die(mysql_error());

    $name = $order->billing_first_name;
    $phone = $order->billing_phone;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_details (order_id, name, phone) VALUES ('$order_id', '$name', '$phone')") or die(mysql_error());
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_db' );
```

Kindly help me out to get the desired functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be inserting data into your wordpress database using the wpdb class.

Something like this:

```
function add_db($order_id) {
global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$name = $order->billing_first_name;
$phone = $order->billing_phone;

global $wpdb;
$table =  $wpdb->prefix . 'order_details';

$wpdb->insert($table, array( 

'order_id' => $order_id,
'name' => $name, 
'phone' => $phone,


));

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_db' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This came up as first result for my search on a similar subject, and I thought I'd contribute. For me, the problem had to do with the fact that woocommerce was picking up and modifying an unfinished order instead of creating a new one when I was running my tests (even if the cart contents changed), so the "new_order" action did not trigger on subsequent runs - which looked like the action not working at all.

Go into the orders tab on the back-end and delete your last unfinished order. Next time you checkout, the "new_order" action should trigger.